# How can I use JavaScript to move content in head tag to the body tag?

Tags: javascript

I need to move some content from head tag into body tag. Can anyone can me some advice please?

Comment: "Some content"? `head` should not really have any content, so I don't really see what it is you want to do...

Comment: What content? I can't imagine it would make any difference once the page is already loaded...

Comment: Do you want the entire content of the body replaced by what's in the head, or instead appended to what's already in the body?  Do you wnat the head's content to be empty when the process finishes or should that content be duplicated so it exists in both the head and the body when complete?

Comment: I see nothing in your `head` tag, I just found a bunch of `script` tags, nothing else :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options are:

1. directly process the html.
2. move stuff around via DOM.

It'd help to know what kind of content you're talking about: from where to to where.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, please check the source code below

view-source:http://www.xuanyinwen.com/test2.html

this is for the google maps, but when I move the javascript to the body, it will not work.

many thanks